# Is heap a table without indexes at all or without a clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, index, clustered-index, nonclustered-index, heap

BOL seems to define a heap as a table without a clustered index.

But many online posts seem to equate a heap to a table without any kind of indexes.

Is there any subtlety I am not aware of?

Thanks

Comment: Heap is a useful term because it refers to the physical data structure. Heaps are stored slightly differently from what SQL Server calls index. The whole clustered/nonclustered terminology is a bit awkward and inconsistent but that's what we have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to be very careful what you read on the interwebs ;-) (of course, that also goes for this answer or pretty much anything anywhere, but still). Just as there is a lot of good information out there, there is also a lot of misinformation (and sadly, this is not confined to technical info). And people copy and paste / repost / share both. So, it is good to ask the question :-).

Eventhough BOL does have some mistakes, in this case (and most cases) it is correct: a Heap is specifically a table without a Clustered index. It has nothing to do with non-Clustered indexes. Of course, this *could* be a simple case of misunderstanding what is being said in these "online posts" since "a table without any kind of indexes" *is* a Heap, but only because having no indexes means that there is no Clustered index. However, if these posts claim that a table with *only* non-Clustered indexes is *not* a Heap, then they would definitely be incorrect.

If you look at `sys.indexes` you will see that `index_id` of `1` is a Clustered Index and `0` is a Heap. A Table will have one or the other. It is not possible to have both. Non-clustered indexes start at `index_id` of 2 and go up from there. All tables will have an index_id of either `0` or `1` and optionally one or more of `index_id` >= `2`.

You can even test this by using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   sys.indexes si
WHERE  si.index_id IN (0, 1)
GROUP BY si.[object_id]
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1;
```

It should never return a row.

Here is a second test which is even more obvious and does not allow for someone to speculate that the condition *can* exist but just doesn't, which I suppose is *possible* with the test above:

```
-- DROP TABLE #tmp;
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Col1 INT, Col2 INT);
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes si WHERE si.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp')
-- 1 row; index_id = 0 and type_desc = HEAP

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_#tmp] ON #tmp (Col2 ASC);
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes si WHERE si.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp')
-- 2 rows; index_id = 0 / HEAP and index_id = 2 / NONCLUSTERED

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_#tmp] ON #tmp (Col1 ASC);
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.indexes si WHERE si.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#tmp')
-- still 2 rows (not 3!!); index_id = 1 / CLUSTERED and index_id = 2 / NONCLUSTERED
```

The point of this second test is that *the* authority on what is and is not true about SQL Server is always going to be SQL Server itself. So it is important to test to essentially ask SQL Server the question, and not a human. Even the experts are sometimes wrong, but SQL Server is always correct (with regards to questions about SQL Server, of course).

---

Also, while this is not "proof" in any definitive way, the title of the following MSDN page is rather telling:

[Heaps (Tables without Clustered Indexes)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. No problem. I just added a second test which shows the answer in a more definite way.

Comment: I would just add to further drive the home point, check out the excellent Clustered Index videos from SQL Skills on TechNet.  Kim Tripp is a major authority, if not the authority, on SQL Indexes and she breaks it down for you well.  In short, a table without a CLUSTERED index is a heap.  It's unsorted.  You can still have indexes on a unclustered index with some additional overhead.  https://www.sqlskills.com/sql-server-resources/sql-server-mcm-training-videos/

Comment: @AliRazeghi Thanks for adding that link. I would only clarify regarding your statement of "_Kim Tripp is ... the authority_" that the one true authority for SQL Server info is SQL Server itself.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. Please see the clarification I just added to the 2nd paragraph. You can see it easily on the [revisions page](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/146859/revisions) (revision 6).

Comment: @srutzky I sometimes do wonder if it is simply that the authors assume readers know they are referring to clustered index only. But then it is really a headache to guess what assumptions the authors have of others reading their posts.

Comment: @JohnSmithSr. Please see the note I just added to the end of my answer. I found it while answering your question related to [compression on heaps](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147263/compression-on-a-heap/147270#147270) :-). And regarding your last comment above: yes, communication is never easy ;-) but that is why I sometimes over-explain (trying to reduce potential ambiguities).

Comment: @srutzky thanks. That page does provide a informative overview.

Answer (score 1):

Srutzky answered the question, but here's another script for testing yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE TestForJohn
(TestID int)

CREATE INDEX IX_Test ON TestForJohn
(TestID)

SELECT t.name, i.type_desc
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
    ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'TestForJohn'

DROP TABLE TestForJohn
```